# F# Script "Error FS0078: Unable to find the file"

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

When I try to run a F# script with FSI (4.1) I get this error on the Windows command shell:

```
stdin<0,1>: error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'open System' in any of C:\..\Desktop
```

I've tried referencing the standard libraries with #I and #r, but have not found a way to make it run.

The script file uses:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing
```

The script runs fine in Visual Studio Code when the code is sent to F# Interactive.

The locations for F# and .NET files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
```

Comment: What is your command line for fsi

Comment: .fsx file type default action is Run: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\fsi.exe" "@%1" %*

Comment: Tried running the script from the command shell and had to add the location of the F# executables to the Windows path variable. The script seems to run, but the created window disappears so fast it's hard to know what's going on. When run via default file type action (Run) I still get the above error message.

Comment: Used two different lines for the Run action and they seem to work, but it's hard to see what's going on. Are all scripts expected to do something then close? The code is supposed to open a Windows form with two buttons that change its background color. I'd expect the script to quit when I close the window, instead of the window closing immediately after it is created.

Comment: The problem is the "@" that you pass as prefix to your argument, it means "read arguments from this file".

Comment: It is working now, Tarmil, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the created window open instead of it closing immediately after execution of the script?

This is my biggest issue with FSI, whatever I want to do in the script I don't get to interact with it.

Comment: @Gordon - canonical method is something like `console.ReadKey() |> ignore`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the way to pause the output. In another comment you stated that it must be "System.console.ReadKey().." to avoid a compiler warning.